# Cuda equivlent of alloca

Tags: cuda

I am wondering if there is a CUDA equivalent of the [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) function.

I need to create arrays of floats which act as the arguments to the mathematical function I am trying to optimize.  The issue is that I don't really want to have to know the number of arguments at compile time which is what I am doing now with templates.  I could use the new operator in CUDA but I feel that it is slow (maybe I could preallocate it or something).  I would use shared memory but it is not big enough.

Comment: Can the number be so high that allocating a large array would be a problem? Is the size only known during the runtime of the kernel? You could also use cudaAllocManaged, which sets up virtual memory. You can overallocate and only the used pages are actually reserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing I am aware of which works like `alloca` for CUDA. The stack frame in the CUDA ABI is statically allocated by the assembler at compile time anyway, so I doubt there would be any scope for dynamically allocating memory on the stack frame

Answer (score 3):

From CUDA 11.3, `alloca` is supported:

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/programming-efficiently-with-the-cuda-11-3-compiler-toolchain/